# Linker error. It is not possible

Tags: c++, opencv, linker

I am trying to use sfm module for opencv. The problem is linking that.
So, let's see the code.

main.cpp:

```
...
    cv::sfm::reconstruct(images_paths, Rs_est, ts_est, K2, points3d_estimated, true)
...
```

I compiled this code to main.o. And now, I would like to link it with libopencv_core.so and libopencv_sfm.so .
The second one file contains a definition of function 'reconstruct'. Why am I sure? When I type:

```
nm -D libopencv_sfm.so | grep reconstruct
```

I got:

```
00000000000b4ca0 T _ZN2cv3sfm11reconstructERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayES6_RKNS_17_InputOutputArrayEb
00000000000b4ba0 T _ZN2cv3sfm11reconstructERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayES6_RKNS_17_InputOutputArrayES6_b
00000000000b2650 T _ZN2cv3sfm11reconstructESt6vectorISsSaISsEERKNS_12_OutputArrayES6_RKNS_17_InputOutputArrayEb
00000000000b2550 T _ZN2cv3sfm11reconstructESt6vectorISsSaISsEERKNS_12_OutputArrayES6_RKNS_17_InputOutputArrayES6_b
```

I checked signature of reconstruct function in main.o file. And it match to:

```
_ZN2cv3sfm11reconstructESt6vectorISsSaISsEERKNS_12_OutputArrayES6_RKNS_17_InputOutputArrayES6_b
```

So the shared library contains definition of reconstruct.

So now, I link:

```
g++ libopencv_core.so libopencv_sfm.so main.o -o main
```

and it gives me error:

```
undefined reference to `cv::sfm::reconstruct(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, bool)'
```

And I don't understand. After all libopencv_sfm.so contains definition of that function!

And please: don't tell me: use cmake. I tried use cmake and the problem is the same. So I try to understand it on low level.

Thanks in advance.

(gcc version: 5.1.1)

Comment: Put libraries *last* on the command line when linking, or at least after the object files that depends on the libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To link a library use `-l` flag and add dependencies after the objects they depend on them:

```
g++ -o main main.o -L. -lopencv_sfm -lopencv_core
```

The `-L.` will search for libearies in current path. Omit if not needed.

Comment: Seems I can't post a new answer because the question is marked as duplicate, so I have a follow-up question: 

 Where your opencv library come from ? Did you built it yourself or did it come from a package of your distro ? (and if yes, which one ?)

You may have been bitten by new gcc5 features such as this one:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html
(tldr: try using -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 when compiling your code)